# On what ascending did "Moses seeing God tying crowns on the letters" happen?

Tags: torah-study, moshe-rabbeinu

To elaborate on Maurice's question "[what-did-moses-understand...](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117284/what-did-moses-understand-in-rabbi-akivas-class)":

> "Rav Yehuda says that Rav says: When Moses ascended on High, he found the Holy One, Blessed be He, **sitting and tying crowns on the letters of the Torah**" [Menachot.29b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Menachot.29b.3?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)

I'm a bit confused here: if it was on the first ascending before the receiving of the Torah (as the commentators suggest by "מי מעכב"), he would definitely expect to learn it later, if it was on the following ascendings, after the receiving of the Torah, why would he see God altering the Torah scroll?

When exactly (on what ascending) did that event happen? (IIRC there were only two?)